# How to set foreign key to a field of another model?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to set a foreign key to a field of another model.

I have tried Foreign Key to_field='field_name'

````
class Banks(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    id = models.IntegerField(unique=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'banks'

class Branches(models.Model):
    ifsc = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False)
    bank_id = models.ForeignKey(Banks, to_field='id', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    branch = models.CharField(max_length=50)```

ProgrammingError: column branches.id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "branches"."id", "branches"."ifsc", "branches"."bank_...
````

Comment: did you makemigrations and migrate

Comment: I had not done that, but while doing it it's throwing an error :
```django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "banks" already exists
```

Comment: You should not use migrations here, since these are legacy tables. As I note in my answer, you should add `managed = False` to prevent migrations being created for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is not caused by the foreign key. The error is happening in the Branches model, which presumably also has a `db_table` Meta attribute and is based on a legacy table.

You *must* define a primary key for your models. If you don't, Django will do so automatically and call it `id`. In the case of your Banks model, you should set that `id` field as `primary_key=True` - or indeed remove it completely, since that is the default. You need to find a suitable pk for Branches as well and declare it in the field.

For your actual question, you don't need to do anything; Django will automatically set the FK to point to the PK of the target model.

```
class Bank(models.Model):
    # removed `id` as that is the default PK
    name = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'banks'

class Branch(models.Model):
    ifsc = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)  # assume this is the PK
    bank = models.ForeignKey(Bank, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    branch = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'branches'
```

Note also, since these are legacy tables you probably want to add `managed = False` to both Meta classes. And as suggested by AKX, it is Django style to make model names singular; you can do that without affecting the table name since that is declared explicitly.

Comment: Should also note that model names should be singular, i.e. `Bank` and `Branch` here.

Comment: After making the changes I am getting the following error:

```
ProgrammingError: column branches.bank_id_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "branches"."ifsc", "branches"."bank_id_id", "branches...
```

Comment: Apologies, the FK should be called just `bank` since Django appends `_id` to the underlying field automatically.

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept the answer, as a sign to future searchers that it solved your problem.

Comment: I have done that. just a follow-up question. How can I show the bank names based on the ids and other details from the branch model in admin? @DanielRoseman

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking, but you probably want to define a `__str__` method on the model class which returns the name.

Answer (score 2):

Just add unique=True in the name column, in the Banks model.

```py
class Banks(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(unique=True) # Just add unique=True
    id = models.IntegerField(unique=True, primary_key=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'banks'

class Branches(models.Model):
    ifsc = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False)
    bank_id = models.ForeignKey(Banks, to_field='id', on_delete=models.CASCADE) # Now it will work
    branch = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```