# how do you assign a foreign key to a boolean field in another table in django

Tags: python, django

hello i am trying to assign a foreign key to a boolean field in my User table which is called seller

here is my code for my code of which is want to have a foreign key assigned to my seller field, which is a boolean field

```
class MyMarketplaceManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, business_name, foods, seller):
        if not business_name:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a email")
        if not seller:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a password")
        if not foods:
            raise ValueError("Sellers must have a menu")
        user = self.model(
            business_name=business_name,
            seller=seller,
            food_item=foods
        )
        user.save(user=self.db)
        return user




class Marketplace(models.Model):
    business_name = models.CharField(max_length=32, default="", primary_key=True)
    seller_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    foods = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=200), blank=True)
    objects = MyMarketplaceManager()
```

the seller id field is what i want to assign the seller field to
i have seen on another question which asks about a primary key which was this

[How to set foreign key to a field of another model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56899446/how-to-set-foreign-key-to-a-field-of-another-model)

but it didn't have anything about other fields

can anyone help?

Comment: You are planning to have a foreign key with only two valid values?

Comment: @KlausD. i am trying to have a foreign key with a boolean value from my user table. thats all

Comment: That does not seem to make any sense.

Comment: @KlausD. is there anything particular in my question which doesn't make sense?

Comment: Yes, a boolean field as foreign key. A foreign key's type should match a foreign field, in many cases a primary key field. And a boolean primary key is not very useful.

Answer (score 0):

You already have user as a FK `seller_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`
If you want to check if that user is a seller. Assuming this boolean field is called `is_seller`

```
User.objects.filter(is_seller=True)
```

This command fill give you all users who are sellers. You can filter it even more to suit your needs

Comment: i think that works i have put that in my views.py file which request if the user is a seller